# Unable to detect if i can connect to mysql via pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$hostname_MYDB = "192.168.0.5";
$database_MYDB = "mydb";
$username_MYDB = "root";
$password_MYDB = "test";

try {
    $MYDBPDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostname_MYDB.";dbname=".$database_MYDB, $username_MYDB, $password_MYDB);
    $MYDBPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    $MYDBPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 1);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "unable to connect to mysql server";
}
```

I run this with mysql server shut-down but it doesn't seem to work, the page keeps loading ( trying to connect ).

the mysql server is running on windows if that makes a difference, php too.

Comment: Can you connect to the DB by other means?

Comment: what's the complete error message ? do you have installed the PDO extension and pdo-mysql driver ?

Comment: I've just tested this on linux and it's working as expected.

Comment: it seems to work if i pass  the attributes as array parameters in the new PDO. solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass the attributes as parameters during the initialization like this

```
$MYDBPDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostname_MYDB.";dbname=".$database_MYDB, $username_MYDB, $password_MYDB, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 1));
```

not later via the setattribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor accepts parameters for specifying the database source (known as the DSN) and optionally for the username and password (if any).See [**Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). The DSN consists of `mysql:host=localhost` AND `dbname`.

In your case.

```
"mysql:host=$hostname_MYDB;dbname=$database_MYDB"
```

Instead of

```
$MYDBPDO = new PDO("mysql:host=".$hostname_MYDB.";dbname=".$database_MYDB, $username_MYDB, $password_MYDB);
```

Try

```
$MYDBPDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_MYDB;dbname=$database_MYDB", $username_MYDB, $password_MYDB);
```